# Eliminar Warning en Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

Cuando creo una interfaz gráfica con Swing en Java y creo un botón, Netbeans me crea un método para tal botón con el siguiente código:

```
private void bSalirActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    dispose();
}
```

NetBeans me tira un Warning indicando que la variable evt nunca es leída, "Variable evt is never read".
Se que los Warning no impiden la ejecución del código. Solo son advertencias, y se que podría desactivar los warnings relacionados con las variables no usadas desde el panel de preferencias, pero, ¿cómo podría eliminar ese warning de otra forma?
No puedo eliminar esa variable porque es una variable que se ejecutará cuando el botón sea presionado, por eso nunca es leída antes de compilar.
Además que no se puede modificar el código en gris en Netbeans.

Comment: Has usado un montón de etiquetas pero justo obvias la que importa en este caso... tu duda no tiene mucha relación con variables, clases, *"variables-globales"* (sea lo que crees que sea eso...) ni java en si mismo. Es una duda de configuración de **netbeans**! Te recomiendo usar las etiquetas correctamente, seguro que es más fácil encontrarle respuesta a tu pregunta así. Por ejemplo, yo uso java a diario en el trabajo pero nunca he tocado Netbeans :)

Comment: De acuerdo. Pensé que sería un error común en cualquier IDE, pero no tenía ni la menor idea.